# Controlling a RTD34005 with 5V

Tags: arduino, mosfet, relay

I am trying to build this [circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.37936678946831776+70+5+50%0A178+64+32+128+32+0+1+0.2+0.04293661806626265+0.075+1000000+0.02+112%0AR+-112+32+-160+32+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-112+32+-16+48+0%0Aw+-16+48+64+64+0%0Aw+64+80+-16+96+0%0Aw+-16+96+-96+96+0%0Ad+-16+96+-16+48+2+1N4148%0Af+-144+192+-96+192+32+1.5+0.06%0AR+-208+192+-208+240+0+0+40+5.88+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-208+192+-192+208+0%0Aw+-96+96+-96+176+0%0Ag+-96+272+-96+336+0%0Aw+-96+208+-96+272+0%0Ar+-144+240+-144+272+0+10000%0Ag+-144+304+-144+336+0%0Aw+-144+272+-144+288+0%0Aw+-144+288+-144+304+0%0Aw+-144+192+-144+240+0%0Ar+-192+208+-160+208+0+1000%0Aw+-160+208+-144+192+0%0A181+288+48+368+48+0+472.5357534188727+100+120+0.4+0.4%0Av+224+-32+144+-32+0+1+40+120+0+0+0.5%0Aw+64+-32+64+32+0%0Aw+368+0+224+-32+0%0Aw+368+0+368+48+0%0Aw+64+-32+144+-32+0%0Aw+128+16+288+48+0%0Ao+20+64+0+4103+160+3.2+0+4+20+3+20+0+20+3%0A38+1+0+1+5+Voltage%0A38+8+0+0+6+Voltage%0A)

[image]

The N-MOSFET(FQP30N06L) is controlled via an Arduino Mega and sourcing the 5V from the Mega as well.

I have tested that the leg is getting 5V across but when I add the relay it lowers the voltage a lot.

[This](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-potter-brumfield-relays/RTD34005/RTD34005-ND/1128660) is the relay I am trying to flip. My ultimate goal is to control a larger 120V AC heating element. Thanks for any help, or suggestions of a different relay.

Comment: Please provide us with the schematic of your circuit. Otherwise it is impossible to guess what your situation is :)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We recommend that you put enough detail into your question that it can stand on its own without your readers having to follow two links to understand the question. (You'll attract more readers too.) The question will also stand on its own if the links die.

Comment: Sorry for the requirement to follow links. But in general I just want to know what I am missing besides 5v to flip the relay. Is there a standard practice for sharing a spec sheet?

Comment: In this case all that's going to be important is the relay coil resistance since that's most likely what is pulling down the voltage. The catalog page that you've linked to says it draws 80.6 mA. Can your Mega provide that much current without the on-board voltage regulator overheating and going into current limit?

Comment: @Transistor I tried supplying the 5V via a larger power supply with 400mA and it still doesn't flip. At least all the way, but you can hear it move on both power sources. Just isn't enough to fully close it. Any way to get around it? Or suggestions of one that would be easier to drive?

Comment: "*...  it lowers the voltage a lot.*" Why not quite numerical voltage readings?

Comment: Thank you for the help, It was dropping to 1.2V. I found that if I removed the 1K resistor on the N-MOSFET it allowed 3.56V on the coil for the relay and it fully activated. Thanks again. So I was guess I was just dividing the signal voltage from the Arduino Mega to much. Thanks again

Comment: There is **something wrong** if your supply voltage is not dropping (still 5.0V give or take) and you are only getting 3.56V across the coil. Maybe the MOSFET is not what you think it is, because it's supposed to be a logic-level MOSFET, and with 5V drive it should *literally* drop only a few mV when on.

Comment: I updated the question to include the MOSFET I am using.  FQP30N06L My signal voltage at the gate is 3.3V. Also with out the relay on that leg I get 5V and with the 3.5V